# ¿Cómo comprobar que hilos se inician en paralelo?

Tags: java

Quiero crear un método tomando como argumento un ID de entero y devolviendo un objeto Ejecutable `Runable` (como clase anónima) que redefine el método para mostrar 10,000 veces "Yo soy el ID de los thread" (O id coincide al entero pasado en el parámetro).

En el método main (), quiero crear dos objetos `Threads`, con el argumento del constructor `Runnables` creado por el método anterior con `id = 1` e `id = 2`. Sin embargo, al ejecutar los hilos con el método start () no soy capaz de comprobar que los hilos se ejecutan en paralelo. En efecto, aquí esta el codigo:

```
class ThreadTest implements Runnable {

    private int id;

    public ThreadTest(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            System.out.println(" Je suis le thread d'id " + this.id);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadTest(1));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadTest(2));

        t1.run();
        t2.run();
    }
}
```

Y siempre me devuelve el primero antes del segundo. Tal vez me equivoque, pero para mí, correr en paralelo () debería haberme dado una mezcla de `Je suis le thread d'id 1` y `Je suis le thread d'id 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los `Threads` se inician con `start` no con `run`, de otro modo el método corre en `Thread` actual.

Cambia:

```
t1.run();
t2.run();
```

Por:

```
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

Una vez que hagas esto, los mensajes deberían salirte intercalados sin un criterio fijo lo que mostraria que corren "en paralelo".